# onbeforeunload JavaScript function should not be called when asp.net treeview node is expanded/collapsed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-events

For unsaved changes if user wants to leave the page `onbeforeunload` event is called to show the confirmation popup, but on just expand or collapse of asp.net treeview this method is called and shows the popup. So how can I stop calling this method on expand or collapse of treeview. Ideally it should only be called for asp.net treeview when I click on any node which does a post back. Please help.

Comment: Please do [not add "urgent" to your title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135880). You will get the opposite effect.

Comment: Are you using Jquery treeview ?

Answer (score 0):

Add onClick to treeview body div, add a function named disableOnBeforeUnload

```
<.... onClick="disableOnBeforeUnload();">
```

`

```
var OnBeforeUnloadDisabled = false;
function disableOnBeforeUnload()
{
  OnBeforeUnloadDisabled = true;
}

window.onbeforeunload = function() { 
  if(!OnBeforeUnloadDisabled)
  {
     //your onbeforeunload code.
  }
};
```

**Notice:** Not tested code, I think you understand the idea.

Comment: I need click event of expand node(parent node) of asp.net treeview. If you have any idea. Please suggest?